# Adding items to string not showing characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

```
    for (NSString *item in items) {
        NSString *ref = [item stringByMatching:myregex1 capture:2];
        NSString *value = [item stringByMatching:myregex1 capture:3];
        NSLog(@"%@ : %@", ref, value);
        AllOrderItems = [AllOrderItems stringByAppendingFormat:(@"%@: %@ \r\n", ref, value)];       

    }
```

the AllOrderItems is not showing the : or the new lines(\r\n) just the ref & value strings ?

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets around your format:

```
AllOrderItems = [AllOrderItems stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@: %@ \r\n", ref, value];
```